# remove specific string from text file using sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed, printing, command

I have a file called `a.txt` that have,

```
time="2022-08-02T15:07:53+05:30" level=info msg="\x1b[32m\x1b[1mPUBLIC\x1b[39m\x1b[0m http://some.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/ (\x1b[33mhttp://some.com\x1b[39m)"
time="2022-08-02T15:07:53+05:30" level=info msg="\x1b[31m\x1b[1mFORBIDDEN\x1b[39m\x1b[0m http://some.s3.amazonaws.com (\x1b[33mhttp://some.com\x1b[39m)"
time="2022-08-02T15:07:54+05:30" level=info msg="\x1b[31m\x1b[1mFORBIDDEN\x1b[39m\x1b[0m http://some.s3.amazonaws.com (\x1b[33mhttp://some.com\x1b[39m)"
time="2022-08-02T15:07:58+05:30" level=info msg="\x1b[31m\x1b[1mFORBIDDEN\x1b[39m\x1b[0m http://some-assets.s3.amazonaws.com (\x1b[33mhttp://some.com\x1b[39m)"
time="2022-08-02T15:08:01+05:30" level=info msg="\x1b[31m\x1b[1mFORBIDDEN\x1b[39m\x1b[0m http://some.s3.amazonaws.com (\x1b[33mhttp://some.com\x1b[39m)"
```

I want this output

```
PUBLIC    http://some.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN http://some.s3.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN http://some.s3.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN http://some-assets.s3.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN http://some.s3.amazonaws.com
```

I tried this

```
cat a.txt | cut -d "=" -f4- | cut -d "[" -f3- | cut -d "m" -f2- |  awk -F '\\.amazonaws.com' '{print $1".amazonaws.com"}'
```

This is working but, I'm not able to remove `\x1b[39m\x1b[0m`

Comment: `cat a.txt | cut -d "=" -f4- | cut -d "[" -f3- | cut -d "m" -f2- |  awk -F '\\.amazonaws.com' '{print $1".amazonaws.com"}'`

This is working but, I'm not able to remove `\x1b[39m\x1b[0m `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's~([^[]*\[){2}[^A-Z]*([^\]*)[^ ]* ([^ ]*\.[a-z]+).*~\2 \3~' input_file | column -t
PUBLIC     http://some.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN  http://some.s3.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN  http://some.s3.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN  http://some-assets.s3.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN  http://some.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk -F= '{gsub(/^.*1m|\/? \(.*$|\\x[^[:blank:]]*/, "", $4); print $4}' file | column -t

PUBLIC     http://some.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN  http://some.s3.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN  http://some.s3.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN  http://some-assets.s3.amazonaws.com
FORBIDDEN  http://some.s3.amazonaws.com
```

Use `column -t` for formatting of output.

Answer (score 0):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code, written and tested in GNU `awk`. This is a GNU `awk` + `column` command's combination. Code is using `match` function of `awk` to get the matched sub string as per required output.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ OFS="\t" }
match($0,/^time=".*level=\S+\smsg="[^[]*\[[^[]*\[1m([^\\]*)\\x1b\S+\s(https?:\/\/\S+)/,arr){
  print arr[1],arr[2]
}
' Input_file | column -t -s $'\t'
```

Comment: not working sir,

Comment: error `awk: line 3: syntax error at or near ,`

Comment: @Shin, hi, it worked fine for me. Have you copy pasted same code and tried just want to make sure because I tested this code successfully

Comment: @Shin you aren't using GNU awk as required for the 3rd arg to match().